# Factor group of a factor groups

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, quotient-group

I solved many questions about factor groups on Gallain's book. One question was

> Let $G=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle 20\rangle}$ and $H=\dfrac{\langle 4\rangle}{\langle 20 \rangle}$. List the elements of $H$ and $\dfrac{G}{H}$.

I solved this question either. But then some question come to my mind, here is my question: What if let $G=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle 10\rangle}$ and $H=\dfrac{\langle 10\rangle}{\langle 20 \rangle}$. List the elements of $H$ and $\dfrac{G}{H}$

$$G=\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle 10\rangle}=\lbrace a\in\langle 10\rangle:a\in \mathbb{Z} \rbrace=\lbrace 
0+\langle10\rangle, 1+\langle10\rangle,...,9+\langle10\rangle \rbrace$$
and
$$H=\dfrac{\langle 4\rangle}{\langle 20\rangle}=\lbrace a\in\langle20\rangle:a\in \langle 20\rangle \rbrace=\lbrace 0+\langle20\rangle, 4+\langle20\rangle,...,16+\langle20\rangle\rbrace$$

However,
$$\dfrac{G}{H}=\lbrace a + H: a\in G \rbrace = \lbrace a+ \dfrac{\langle4\rangle}{\langle20\rangle}:a\in\ \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle10\rangle}  \rbrace = \lbrace (0+\langle 10\rangle)+\dfrac{\langle 4\rangle}{\langle 20\rangle}, (1+\langle 10\rangle)+\dfrac{\langle 4\rangle}{\langle 20\rangle},...,(9+\langle 10\rangle)+\dfrac{\langle 4\rangle}{\langle 20\rangle} \rbrace$$

But I couldn't reduce anymore. By the way I know that this must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$ since:
$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle 10 \rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{10}, \;\; \dfrac{\langle 10 \rangle}{\langle 20\rangle}\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$$
Hence
$$\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}_{10}}{\mathbb{Z}_2} \cong \mathbb{Z}_5$$

However, I couldn't show with definition where is the mistake or the part that I should do. Thanks in advance! Please avoid using first, second and third isomorphism theorems.

Comment: It is more accurate to write, say, $$\Bbb Z/\langle 20\rangle$$ because quotient groups are defined in terms of left/right cosets.

Answer (score 2):

The factor group $\frac{G}{H}$ only exists if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ (a normal subgroup, if $G$ is non-commutative). This is not the case in your example. The element $0+\left\langle20\right\rangle$, for example, is in $H$ but not in $G$.

Comment: Oh I see. So we cannot talk about factor group? Right

Comment: Exactly. The concept of a factor groups requires that of a coset, which in turn requires _H_ to be a subgroup of _G_.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my nearly 1 or 2 hours of searching that!

Comment: $\Bbb Z_5\le\Bbb Z_{20}$.

Comment: $0+\langle 20\rangle \in G$.

Comment: It is not. Every element in $G=\mathbb{Z}/\left\langle 10\right\rangle$ is of the form $a+\left\langle 10\right\rangle$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. The only such coset containing $0$ is $0+\left\langle 10\right\rangle=\left\{...,-10,0,10,20,,...\right\}$. This is not the coset $0+\left\langle 20\right\rangle=\left\{...,-20,0,20,...\right\}$, which is the only one in $H$ to contain $0$.